# NotSupportedException was caught

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq, wcf

I have an WCF Method where I do a join between two tables. now I have encountered this error:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 Parse(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

As I looked with a breakpoint my variable I create in my Operation Contract shows `undefined` When running through the coding.

**Operation Contract**

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "GET", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, UriTemplate = "getRepByCompA/{CompanyID}")]
List<Represetative> GetRepByCompA(string CompanyID);
```

**Service Method**

```
  public List<Represetative> GetRepByCompA(string CompanyID)
  {
      try
      {
          TruckDb db = new TruckDb();

          List<Represetative> RepList = new List<Represetative>();

          var join = from t in db.Companies
                   join p in db.Represetatives on t.Id equals p.CompanyId
                   where t.Id == int.Parse(CompanyID) *//<-Shows CompanyID is Undefined-*
                   select new { t, p };

          foreach (var item in join)
          {
              Represetative ph = new Represetative();

              //REPRESETATIVES
              ph.Name = item.p.Name;
              ph.Email = item.p.Email;
              ph.ContactNumber = item.p.ContactNumber;
              ph.Quotes = item.p.Quotes;
              ph.CompanyId = item.p.Id;
              //REPRESETATIVES

              //COMPANY
              ph.Id = item.t.Id;
              //COMPANY

              RepList.Add(ph);
          }

          return RepList;

      }
      catch (Exception)
      {
          throw;
      }
  }
```

When I tried to change CompanyID to an int I get this error when running my service:

> Operation 'GetRepByCompA' in contract 'ITruckService' has a path variable named 'CompanyID' which does not have type 'string'. ÿVariables for UriTemplate path segments must have type 'string'.

Comment: Can't you pass CompanyID as an integer instead of string?

Comment: No, that is what I mentioned at the bottom it says it needs to be a string value? @dimitarie

Comment: Convert id to `int` from outside: `var id = int.Parse(CompanyID); var join = from ... where where t.Id == id ...;`

Comment: It gives me this error: `Input string was not in a correct format.` @Dennis

Comment: @RGdent: I suppose, `CompanyId` does not contain an integer. Could you look at `CompanyId` in debugger before parsing?

Comment: Yes it shows `Undefined` @Dennis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are four problems.

1. EF LINQ provider can't translate every valid C# expression to SQL, that's why you're getting `NotSupportedException`. To avoid it, you have to convert `CustomerId` from `string` to `int` before LINQ expression.
2. According to your comments, there are optional possibility to pass `Undefined` string as `CompanyID`. Obviously, this can't be parsed into integer. I assume, that `Undefined` means "any". Hence, you need to throw away `where` condition, if `CompanyID` is `Undefined`.
3. Your projection uses noting from `db.Companies` but company `Id`, which is already presents in `db.Represetatives` as `CompanyId`. You don't need join at all.
4. Assuming, that type of items in `db.Represetatives` differs from `Represetative`, you can select `Represetative` directly, without intermediate projection into anonymous type and filling list by hand.

Your method could be re-written like this:

```
// this assumes, that "RepresetativeEntityType" is a type name of representative entity
IQueryable<RepresetativeEntityType> representatives = db.Represetatives;

// pre-filter representatives, if CompanyID could be parsed
int companyIdToFilter;
if (int.TryParse(CompanyID, out companyIdToFilter))
{
    representatives = representatives
        .Where(_ => _.CompanyId == companyIdToFilter);
}

return representatives
    .Select(_ => new Represetative
    {
       //REPRESETATIVES
       Id = _.Id,
       Name = _.Name,
       Email = _.Email,
       ContactNumber = _.ContactNumber,
       Quotes = _.Quotes,

       //COMPANY
       CompanyId = _.CompanyId
    })
    .ToList();
```

Note, that if type of items in `db.Represetatives` *is* `Represetative`, you even don't need projection, just remove `Select` and call `ToList`.

Comment: The Undefined value is from my selection changed value in a dropdown of my application.. @Dennis

Comment: never mind sorry your solution dit fix this error thanks

Answer (score 0):

Replace this string:

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "GET", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, UriTemplate = "getRepByCompA/{CompanyID}")]
List<Represetative> GetRepByCompA(string CompanyID);
```

To this:

```
[WebGet(UriTemplate="/GetRepByCompA?CompanyID={CompanyID}", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, UriTemplate = "getRepByCompA/{CompanyID}")]
List<Represetative> GetRepByCompA(string CompanyID);
```

And parse your CompanyID variable before the Linq operation:

```
int cid = int.Parse(CompanyId);
var join = from t in db.Companies
           join p in db.Represetatives on t.Id equals p.CompanyId
           where t.Id == cid 
           select new { t, p };
```

Comment: Why do you change it to WebGet? @Tequila

Comment: First of all it something like a good practice when you declaring your operation contract working via GET Http Verb.

Comment: having both Uri Templates gives an error of duplication: `'UriTemplate' duplicate named attribute argument` @Tequila

Comment: It is becouse you have similar UriTemplate in your interface. Just rename the UriTemplate with unique name. For example, uriTemplate="/GetRepByCompany?CompanyID={CompanyID}", ...

Comment: I did but error still remains @Tequila would you mind to explain why you use two UriTemplates maybe if I understand better I can work around it?

Comment: No no no, we use just one UriTemplate. I just name it with the name similar to your method name. Of course you can use any name wich you want or not use in general but you have to set up the parameter CompanyId in this UriTemplate.

Comment: Could you tell me what kind of error do you get now ? After the replacing your code with my variant

Comment: The Same error `'UriTemplate' duplicate named attribute argument `@Tequila

Comment: Could you tell me do you have methods with the same name or UriTemplates in your serviceContract (in your interface)? And try to replace UriTemplate, for example, to this "/representative?CompanyId={CompanyID}"

Comment: No there isn't any methods with the same name.. @Tequila

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97254/discussion-between-tequila-and-rgdent).